# What kind of roles/line of work value ability to take criticism and maintain a level head with high cultural awareness?

Tags: career-development, cultural-sensitivity

According to plum.io I'm really good at those. So in my scoping out where I could add value, I'd be really interested in roles that emphasise those soft skills over social skills, as I'm much more likely to be a good fit. I'd also be interested in any roles/careers that might fit . ( i figure form a role name, I can work out a career path/progression.
For reference I've included the whole profile.

## Profile

### Cultural Awareness

Your Cultural Awareness is in the top 15% of the workforce. You have a strong proficiency for understanding the perspective of others, and dealing effectively with different types of people.

You have an extraordinary disposition for being curious, reflective and studying people and their values.

You have a disposition for adapting to a wide range of people, and being open to differences in attitudes, values and personalities.

You can be encouraging, sensitive, and make others feel comfortable and appreciated.

You have an extraordinary ability to communicate in a tactful and considerate manner in difficult situations, and help others settle interpersonal conflicts.

...

### Adaptation

You have a proficiency for adjusting to changes in the workplace while maintaining a positive demeanor.

You can remain calm, level-headed and operate effectively in the midst of stressful situations and under multiple or conflicting demands.

You have an extraordinary ability to change your approach to best fit the situation, analyze problems and develop new solutions.

You can learn and apply new skills, adjust effectively to different and changing environments, and smoothly integrate changes into your work habits.

You have an extraordinary ability to deal positively with obstacles and failures, accept criticism and feedback, and use intuition and experience to complement data.

...

### Conflict Resolution

You have a good ability to stay calm and collected in stressful situations or when confronted with criticism.

You are supportive and sensitive to the feelings of others, helping you find mutually agreeable solutions.

You have an extraordinary temperament for being polite and mannerly when interacting with others even when you disagree.

### Professionally, you are...

Exceptionally well suited to positions that will demand continuous learning and imagining new and different ways of doing things.

Well suited to organizations and positions that appreciate good listeners that don't waste time on simple chit-chat.

Exceptionally well suited to positions with altruistic goals and tasks that make people happy.

Best suited to positions that are unlikely to have many unexpected problems or changes in how the work gets done.

Better suited to positions where social relationships are not important, and where there is frequently space to work alone.

Exceptionally well suited to positions that require close collaboration, soliciting and accepting feedback and criticism, and dealing positively with obstacles and failures.

### At work, you...

Delight in thinking about abstract ideas and a variety of subjects.
Appreciate working in small teams or alone.

Greatly appreciate opportunities to collaborate and cooperate with others.

Greatly prefer learning by repetition and accomplishing objectives that are well explained ahead of time.

Greatly appreciates who you are as a person and see yourself in a positive light.

Comment: Sorry, but this profile reads like the professional equivalent of a horoscope.  What tangible skills (e.g. engineering, math, finance, trade skills such as electrical or carpentry, etc.) do you have?  Those are what you should center any career search around instead.

Comment: Please specify your professional background and interest.These evaluations are too generic and not primarily relevant to give advice in chosing a career path.

Comment: An analysis that managed to tell you that you "Appreciate working [...] alone" and then in the very next sentence says "appreciate to collaborate and cooperate with others" is not worth the electrons it was transmitted on. This is bullshit bingo with ego-stroking adjectives, not an analysis. Just imagine your counterpart that is exactly *not* you. Turn this analysis around. Can you see a valid analysis to the contrary?

Comment: Government work

Comment: Just the last paragraph. I read "not capable of doing anything concrete, and focusing on the required task. Can't work in a larger team. Requires others to do the work. Can't figure out anything on his own, needs to be told what to do all the time and can't do any one-time items. In love with yourself and deluded". While this website tried to put everything into a positive light, that's the same person seen in a negative light. Maybe you should apply at plum.io for a job.

Answer (score 7):

Those are all great characteristics that are beneficial in literally every single profession. Things like work ethic, integrity, and general life skills will benefit you everywhere.

However, Plum.io is a business and they want you to buy their product. They fed you a bunch of generic, unspecified, ego-boosting character trait analysis so that you will buy their product.

Finding what career you should pursue is a lot harder than that. A good place to **start** is finding something you love, something you are good at, or both.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but is this a hidden ad for the web service you mentioned?

**You should apply for jobs that fit your professional education, experience and interests first and your social skills second !**

So it would be great to know what your professional / educational background is.

Or are you asking us what kind of profession you should start learning as a student?

Because most of the skills you mentioned are welcome wherever you work with people in teams or directly with customers... so almost everywhere...so not really helpful to give any meaningful advice.

While sounding really good, what you wrote sounds also too generic in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through this carefully, there are two rather damning lines:

"Best suited to positions that are unlikely to have many unexpected problems or changes in how the work gets done."

"Better suited to positions where social relationships are not important, and where there is frequently space to work alone"

These two lines are *not good*. But they are completely contradicted by this line: "Exceptionally well suited to positions that require close collaboration, soliciting and accepting feedback and criticism, and dealing positively with obstacles and failures." Well, what is it? Alone or collaboration? No unexpected problems, or dealing positively with obstacles and failures?

Another damning one is: "Greatly prefer learning by repetition and accomplishing objectives that are well explained ahead of time."

This very much looks like one of those personality tests that are meant to make you feel good, without actually saying anything meaningful about you. And still they manage to put in some lines that you maybe found positive, but they absolutely are not.

Throw this nonsense away. Figure out what you like to do, and what you are good at. Then do it.

Oh well. I probably don't have an extraordinary ability to communicate in a tactful and considerate manner, but then you have an extraordinary ability to accept criticism and feedback, so that's fine.

And please, don't post this stuff on LinkedIn or any such site. Half of potential employers will laugh, the other half will cry.